# require_once(C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\pages\ecommerce.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:

Tags: php

```
Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\pages\ecommerce.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\classes\Core.php on line 59
```

I'm following the project videos of one of the Web Ecommerce project using PHP,MYSQL.

Here is my `run()` method Throwing error:

```
public function run() {

        ob_start();


        switch ($this->objUrl->module) {
            case 'panel':
                set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
                    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.'admin'.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
                    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.'admin'.DS.PAGES_DIR),
                    get_include_path()
                    )));
                require_once(ROOT_PATH.DS.'admin'.DS.PAGES_DIR.DS.
                    $this->objUrl->cpage.'.php');
                break;

            default:
                set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
                    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
                    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR),
                    get_include_path()
                    )));
                require_once(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR.DS.
                    $this->objUrl->cpage.'.php');

        }



        ob_get_flush();
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Want to get this error solved........ it say there is no file named ecommerce.php,         and my pages directory also not contains ecommerce.php file..

Comment: Is the file in that directory? Are the permissions set correctly?

Comment: i'm following video training... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcRTQSxQnrk&index=233&list=PLqFzAye41wZEiHygN2jky9poLFKjUBd5d,                       upto that point there was no ecommerce file................................    but my project still got .htaccess file                                          <IfModule module_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewrietCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: It looks like you might have skipped something. The .htaccess file has nothing to do with the ecommerce module.

Comment: can it be php version error.. ???

Comment: Nope, this has nothing to do with a PHP version error.

Comment: i've repeated my code 2 times, going for the third time.. its a quire hectic job out there...